# Date pegando hora de outro fuso horario

Tags: ios, swift

estou com um grande problema, preciso armazenar a data e horário selecionada pelo usuário para poder gerar as notificações na hora correta. A data e hora é capturada por um date picker e quando o pego como String vem da maneira correta "27 de set de 2016 13:04", porém quando vou fazer a conversão para NSDate a hora fica zoado,  2016-09-27 16:04.
Alguém poderia ajudar a solucionar esse problema?
Estou fazendo os teste com o iPhone e não no simulador

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm"
    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
    let date2:NSDate!
        date2 = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateStr4)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"

    if let unwrappedDate = date2 {

        print(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(unwrappedDate))// aqui aparece a data e hora de maneira correta 27/09/2016 13:09
        print("--->",unwrappedDate) // aqui a hora já fica zoada 27/09/2016 16:09
        criaNotificacoes(unwrappedDate, comIntervalo: util.valorIntervalo(campoIntervalo.text!), totalDias: util.valorTempoDias(campoPeriodo.text!))
    }else{
        print("tratar erro ")
    }
```

Comment: Quando voce print a data, vai aparecer sempre a hora sem o fuso (UTC/GMT time), não se preocupe com isso, a data não guarda a sua time zone, voce so precisa dela na hora de mostrar pro usuário e a hora que vai aparecer vai depender da localização do usuário no momento que voce faz o display da data usando o DateFormatter.

Comment: Quando você receber uma String com data da sua API e tiver no final `+0000` ou `Z` significa UTC/GMT time

Answer (score 0):

Você está dando print, porém não está salvando a data correta em nenhuma constante. Tente salvar `dateFormatter.stringFromDate(unwrappedDate)` em uma constante e chamar ela no código no lugar de `unwrappedDate`.

Mais ou menos assim:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm"
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
let date2:NSDate!
    date2 = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateStr4)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"

if let unwrappedDate = date2 {
    let data = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(unwrappedDate)
    print(data)
    print("--->", data)
    criaNotificacoes(data, comIntervalo: util.valorIntervalo(campoIntervalo.text!), totalDias: util.valorTempoDias(campoPeriodo.text!))
}else{
    print("tratar erro ")
}
```